# May I perform medical experimentation on myself without licensure?

Tags: united-states, texas, medical

I'm a retired cellular biologist and medical researcher whose license has been revoked, but I would like to continue a line of research with myself as my subject/patient.  The research involves implanting a device into my uterus, so no incisions are made necessarily, though I will need to administer an IV and ultra-sound upon myself.

I'd also like to extract some of my eggs to perform developmental observations on the side, would those be considered a part of my anatomy in the eyes of the law?  If fertilized, at what point would I need to destroy the samples?